# Is it possible to use a more powerful dyno to build an app on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

The build time for my Heroku app is quite slow, especially when compared with building it on my local development machine.

It's possible to specify the dyno type being used for app instances, including one-off instances, to use more powerful hardware. Is there any way to specify the dyno type used for builds?

Alternatively, are there any good workarounds for slow build times? Perhaps building with a different service and then deploying that pre-built image/tarball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. All Heroku builds run on [Performance-M](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types) dynos.

Comment: Interesting, so it's already using one of their fastest dyno types. Is the use of Performance-M dynos for this publicly documented anywhere?

Comment: Performance-M is still used for builds in 2021. This was confirmed for me in a conversation with Heroku Support this week. They also confirmed that "the build dyno type is not configurable"